# How to change onclick location.href in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new in jquery and javascript. I don't know how to replace the url on onclick location.href in div.

From:

```
<div onclick="location.href='http://sample.com?bo_table=movie&wr_id=756'" id="movie_list">
```

To:

```
<div onclick="location.href='myfile.php?bo_table=movie&wr_id=756'" id="movie_list">
```

I do web parsing and when I click the data I don't want to go directly to the website all I want is to go directly to my parse file.

Comment: Looks ok to me. What is the problem? Press F12 and look in the console and network tabs

Comment: don't use inline js - it's bad practice that leads to hard-to maintain code

Comment: @mplungjan i think the to is an example of what he wants, not what's happened

Comment: Can you give more details? Under which circumstances do you want the link to change?

Comment: `document.querySelector('#movie_list').setAttribute(name, value)` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Comment: @MateuszJ, yes I want to change the url but I want to remain the query string

Comment: i guess the browser don't know what to do with myfile.php without telling its source (i.e. the server)...so just add the server previous to your file. post the result please - have a look in your console and post the error if there's one

Comment: I like how ambiguous questions cause chaos on SO! :)

Answer (score 2):

**Replace using JS**

```
document.querySelector('#movie_list').setAttribute("onclick", "location.href='myfile.php?bo_table=movie&wr_id=756'")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will modify the first `div` on the page. You should use an `id` for a selector if it is present in order to only modify the desired `div` - "movie_list".

Comment: There is no guarantee that `getElementsByTagName("div")[0]` will select the desired target element. The `.setAttribute` part is correct!

Comment: @undefined thanks for your comments

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you want.

If you want to click on a div and go somewhere, use

```js
$(function() {
  $(".movie_list").on("click", function() {
    var href=$(this).data("href");
    location.href = href;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-href="https://sample.com?bo_table=movie&wr_id=756" class="movie_list">Sample.com</div>
<div data-href="myfile.php?bo_table=movie&wr_id=756" class="movie_list">myfile.php</div>
```

If you want to change the href, use this

```js
$(function() {
  $(".movie_list").on("click", function() {
    var href=$(this).data("href");
    location.href = href.replace("http://sample.com","myfile.php");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-href="https://sample.com?bo_table=movie&wr_id=756" class="movie_list">Sample.com</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the `window.location.href` property on `#movie_list` [`click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) event.

```
$('#movie_list').on('click', function() {
    window.location.href = 'myfile.php?bo_table=movie&wr_id=756'
});
```

Comment: please copy the new href into your browser. what happens? right..."source not found" since the server is missing!

Comment: Hi @meistermuh I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: change the address line of your browser to `myfile.php?bo_table=movie&wr_id=756` and hit enter. it won't work since the server is missing. that means that `https://www.some_server.com` must be present ahead the myfile.php

Comment: `window.location.href = 'myfile.php?bo_table=movie&wr_id=756'` will append 'myfile.php?bo_table=movie&wr_id=756' to your current url

Comment: did you try it? I did and there's a "source not found" then. the file that I tried to use exists on my server in the same path. no server was appended. maybe its because of some security reasons on that server...i dont know

Comment: @meistermuh yes I have tried it on developer console.

Comment: well then, I take it back :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I made trouble to you guys. After a few hours I made it. By the way here is the code.

```
$('#movie_list').each(function() {
var href = $(this).attr('onclick').replace("location.href='http://sample.com" , "location.href='myfile.php");
$(this).attr('onclick', href);});
```